# rampart encryption error when execute WSO2 sample 100 (a WS-Security sample)

Tags: ws-security, rampart, wso2-esb

My WSO2-ESB throws following error message when I execute WSO2 sample 100 (a WS-Security sample), http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/qos_mediation_samples.html):

```
ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error in encryption
    At org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:117)
....
    org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: Illegal key size or default parameters
```

And my WSO2-AS throws:

```
ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  Missing wsse:Security header in request org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request
```

What is "Illegal key size or default parameters" means? How to fix this error?

BTW, I am using JDK 1.6 which has included the JCE API and local_policy.jar, US_export_policy.jar, et al. So, I guess it isn't a JCE problem. (http://wso2.org/node/2520/print)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to patch local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar which are relevant to your jdk version.

Please refer http://blog.rampartfaq.com/2009/08/faq-001-javasecurityinvalidkeyexception.html

--
Thilini

Answer (score 0):

Type in cmd: java -version, check whether this version is equal to the version displayed at the startup of wso2.

If these versions were not equal, modify your path and put %JAVA_HOME%\bin before %SystemRoot%\system32.